# HiltWorker cannot inject dependency

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, coroutineworker

I want to use Coroutine worker with with hilt dependency injection.

Worker is running if constructor has only two parameters. context and workerParams;

When I add another dependency it is throwing an exception.

[image]

Below my code:

Manifest:
[image]

App:

[image]

Worker:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a bit research, I find an answer. I should add the dependency

[image]

After adding that dependency. The worker is running fine